# PHP stops execution when calling external function

Tags: php, execution

When the following PHP script executes:

```
<?php

include "imageManager.php";
include "imageHandling/spritesheet.php";
include "updateWindow.php";
include_once "dbConnection.php";

class deleteSoftware{

    private $conn;
    private $tableName;

    public function __construct($name){

      //Database Connection
      $this->connectDatabase(); 

      //Delete the Icon from the image pool
      $tempFileManagerObject = new fileManager();
      $tempFileManagerObject->setSrc("../ICONS/");
      $deletedImageName = $tempFileManagerObject->getImageNameFromSoftwareName($name);
      $tempFileManagerObject->delete("../ICONS/", $deletedImageName);
      $tempFileManagerObject->deleteImageRenaming($deletedImageName);

     //Deleting the record from the database
     $prio = $tempFileManagerObject->getPriorityFromSoftwareName($name);
     $subCategory = $tempFileManagerObject->getSubCategoryFromSoftwareName($name);
     $this->tableName = $subCategory;
     $this->conn->query("delete from ".$subCategory." where priority=".$prio);
     $this->decrementPriorityInTable($prio);

     //Delete from updateWindow if exist
     $updateObject = new updateWindow();
     $updateObject->deleteUpdate($name);

      //Making sprite Sheet and moving to home directory
      echo "step-0";
      $spriteSheetObject = new spriteSheet(18, 18, 5, "../ICONS/", "../");
      echo "step-1";
      for ($x = 1; $x <= $spriteSheetObject->getImageCount(); $x++){ $tempFileManagerObject->copy("../ICONS/", "../Processing/", $x); }
      echo "step-3";
      $spriteSheetObject->setImagesFolder("../Processing/");
      echo "step-4";
      $spriteSheetObject->setOutPutFolder("../");
      $spriteSheetObject->processSpriteSheet();
      $spriteSheetObject->processSpriteSheetCss($this->getTotalSoftwaresCount());
      for ($x = 1; $x <= $spriteSheetObject->getImageCount(); $x++){ $tempFileManagerObject->delete("../Processing/",$x); }
      $tempFileManagerObject->setSrc("../Processing/");
      $tempFileManagerObject->setDes("../");
      $tempFileManagerObject->rename("tempArea", "home");
      $tempFileManagerObject->move("../Processing/", "../", "home");




    }   
    public function connectDataBase(){

        $temp = new dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $temp->connectDb();

}
    public function getTheImageNameOfNewlyInsertedIcon($subCategory, $pri){


        //First of all calculate the iconName of newly inserted image
            //-Get the total number of rows for each subCategory table and add it untill we reach at the subCategory table where software to be inserted (Not add subCategory table rows count)
            //- RowCounts + maxPriority in that table + 1
                //- If there is already software for 



        //Calculating the total number of rows upto subCateogryTable excluding the subCategoryTable and then add up
        $temp = false;
        $rowCount = 0;
        $this->tableName;
        $this->conn->query("use windows");

        $softwareTable = $this->conn->query("select * from software order by priority");
        foreach ( $softwareTable as $row ) {
            $categoryTable = $this->conn->query("select * from ".$row["tableName"]." order by priority");
            foreach ( $categoryTable as $row2 ) {
                $subCategoryTable = $this->conn->query("select * from ".$row2["tableName"]." order by priority");
                if (!strcmp($row2["category"], $subCategory)){
                    $this->tableName = $row2["tableName"];
                    $temp = true;
                    break;
                }
         $rowCount = $subCategoryTable->rowCount() + $rowCount;
            }
            if ($temp){break;}
        }


      $rowCount = $pri + $rowCount;

      return $rowCount;//This will be the name of the image




        //Navigate to Tables
        //According to priority set the iconName
        //Record the iconName please
        //Insert the record in table
        //Execute the spritesheet
        //make css
        //finally iterate the whole database and send a string






    }
    public function decrementPriorityInTable($pri){

        $this->conn->query("use windows");

        $softwareTable = $this->conn->query("select * from ".$this->tableName." order by priority");
        foreach ( $softwareTable as $row ) {
            if($row["priority"] >= $pri+1){
                $this->conn->query("update ".$this->tableName." set priority=".($row["priority"]-1)." where priority=".$row["priority"]);
            } 
        }


    }
    public function getTotalSoftwaresCount(){

        $softwareCount = 0;

        $softwareTable = $this->conn->query("select * from software order by priority");
        foreach ( $softwareTable as $row ) {
            $categoryTable = $this->conn->query("select * from ".$row["tableName"]." order by priority");
            foreach ( $categoryTable as $row2 ) {
                $subCategoryTable = $this->conn->query("select * from ".$row2["tableName"]." order by priority");
                foreach ($subCategoryTable as $row3){
                   $softwareCount++;
                }

            }

        }

        $softwareCount++;
        return $softwareCount;
    }

}



?>
```

The line `$spriteSheetObject = new spriteSheet(18, 18, 5, "../ICONS/", "../");` stops executions without any error.

The `spriteSheet` class comes from this library:

```
    <?php

    require("lib/WideImage.php");


    //All the images size must first be set to be placed on canvas
    //Depends on only 1-Image "canvasArea.jpg"
    //image processing folder is by default a "imagesToBeProcessed"
    //output folder is empty by default



    class spriteSheet{

        private $canvasWidth;
        private $canvasHeight;
        private $eachImageWidth;
        private $eachImageHeight;
        private $imagesFolder = "";
        private $outputFolder = "";
        private $imageCount = 0;
        private $maxImageInARow;

        function __construct($imgW=43,$imgH=43, $maxInRow=5, $src, $des){
            $this->imagesFolder = $src;
            $this->outputFolder = $des;
            $this->imageCounter();
            $this->eachImageWidth = $imgW;
            $this->eachImageHeight = $imgH;
            $this->canvasWidth = $imgW * $maxInRow;
            $this->canvasHeight = $imgH * ceil($this->imageCount/$maxInRow);
            $this->maxImageInARow = $maxInRow;

        }
        public function setImagesFolder($src){
            $this->imagesFolder = $src;
        }    
        public function setOutPutFolder($des){
            $this->outputFolder = $des;
        }
        public function imageCounter( ){
            for ($x=1; true; $x++){
                if (!file_exists($this->imagesFolder.$x.".jpg") and !file_exists($this->imagesFolder.$x.".png") and !file_exists($this->imagesFolder.$x.".gif")){
                    $this->imageCount = $x;
                    break;
                }
            }

           $this->imageCount--;
        }
        public function setCanvasSize( ){

            $canvas = WideImage::load($this->imagesFolder."canvasArea.jpg")->resize($this->canvasWidth, $this->canvasHeight, "fill");
            $canvas->saveToFile($this->imagesFolder."tempArea.jpg");
        }
        public function resizeAllIcons( ){


            $loopEnable = true;

            for ($x=1; $loopEnable == true; $x++){
                if (file_exists($this->imagesFolder.$x.".jpg")){
                    $iconImage = WideImage::load($this->imagesFolder.$x.".jpg")->resize($this->eachImageWidth, $this->eachImageHeight, "fill");
                    $iconImage->saveToFile($this->imagesFolder.$x.".jpg");
                }
                else if (file_exists($this->imagesFolder.$x.".png")){
                    $iconImage = WideImage::load($this->imagesFolder.$x.".png")->resize($this->eachImageWidth, $this->eachImageHeight, "fill");
                    $iconImage->saveToFile($this->imagesFolder.$x.".png");
                }
                else if (file_exists($this->imagesFolder.$x.".gif")){
                    $iconImage = WideImage::load($this->imagesFolder.$x.".gif")->resize($this->eachImageWidth, $this->eachImageHeight, "fill");
                    $iconImage->saveToFile($this->imagesFolder.$x.".gif");
                }
                else{
                $loopEnable = false;
                }
            }

        }
        public function processSpriteSheet( ){

            $this->resizeAllIcons();
            $this->setCanvasSize();

            $row=0; $col=0; $tempImageCounter = 1;

            while ($tempImageCounter<=$this->imageCount){

                $icon;

                if (file_exists($this->imagesFolder.$tempImageCounter.".jpg")){
                    $icon = WideImage::load($this->imagesFolder.$tempImageCounter.'.jpg');
                }
                else if (file_exists($this->imagesFolder.$tempImageCounter.".png")){
                    $icon = WideImage::load($this->imagesFolder.$tempImageCounter.'.png');
                }
                else if (file_exists($this->imagesFolder.$tempImageCounter.".gif")){
                    $icon = WideImage::load($this->imagesFolder.$tempImageCounter.'.gif');
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }

                $canvas = WideImage::load($this->imagesFolder."tempArea.jpg");
                $canvas->merge($icon, $row*$this->eachImageWidth, $col*$this->eachImageHeight, 100)->saveToFile($this->imagesFolder."tempArea.jpg");
                $tempImageCounter++;
                $row++;
                if ($row == $this->maxImageInARow){
                    $row=0;
                    $col++;
                }
            }


        }
        public function processSpriteSheetCss($maxImageCss){
            echo "maxImage:".$maxImageCss;

            $imgCommon = "img.common{
                          width: ".$this->eachImageWidth."px;
                          height: ".$this->eachImageHeight."px;
                          background-image:url(home.jpg);
                          }";

            $imgS=""; $y=0; $tempImageCounter = 1;

            for($x=0; $tempImageCounter<=$maxImageCss; $x++){
                $imgS = $imgS."img.s".$tempImageCounter."{background-position:".-1*($x*$this->eachImageWidth)."px ".-1*($y*$this->eachImageHeight)."px;}";
                if ($tempImageCounter%$this->maxImageInARow == 0){
                    $x = -1;
                    $y++;
                }
                $tempImageCounter++;
            }

            echo "SpriteSheetCSS".$imgS;
            $handle = fopen( "../css/sprite.css", "w" );
            fwrite($handle, $imgS);

        }


        public function getImageCount(){
        echo "total number of images-->".$this->imageCount;
        return $this->imageCount;
        }


    }




    ?>
```

My script stops execution at that line without any error.

This file works perfectly on localhost but when I put this online and execute it then this problem happens.

Comment: You are likely missing some dependencies on your remote server. Can you verify what PHP extensions (ImageMagick etc.) your libraries might require, and whether they are present on both local and remote servers? Also, is your remote server error reporting configured to display errors?